# Compare variable with character

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hello I'm using django templating with this template:

```
{% if material.unit =='U' %} 
    p/(u)
{% endif %}
{% if material.unit == 'M' %} 
    p/(m)
{% endif %}
```

I want to print p/(u) when variable material.unit is 'U' and p/(m) when is 'M'.
This is not working properly. Is giving me this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '=='U'' from '=='U''
```

Comment: Looking at [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50213940/113962) it seems as if you are using regular Django templates, not Jinja2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space after `==`:

```
{% if material.unit == 'U' %}
```